# Code using Tkinter works in IDLE but not in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, terminal

This is (part of) my very first program. It uses Tkinter to output text in a scrolled textbox. I used Python 3.6.4 and IDLE and it works perfectly, but when I run it from terminal/Atom once I click `ok` after selecting the options from the dropdown menus it just closes without errors, while in IDLE it correctly outputs all the text in the textbox.

I want to use Py2app to make a standalone, but for this the code needs to execute properly from terminal.

Here are the main snippets from the code. I'm just coding for a few months so any detailed help would be much appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from collections import OrderedDict
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *
from collections import Counter

master = Tk()
master.title("App")
master.geometry("600x665")
master.lift()
master.attributes('-topmost', True)

mvar = IntVar()
mvar1 = IntVar()

var = StringVar(master)
var.set("Asc")
var1 = StringVar(master)
var1.set("Ar")

x = OptionMenu(master, var, "Ar", "Ta", "Ge","Can","Le","Vi","Li","Sc","Sa","Cap","Aq","Pi")
x.grid(column =2,row =1)

x1 = OptionMenu(master, var1, "Ar", "Ta", "Ge","Can","Le","Vi","Li","Sc","Sa","Cap","Aq","Pi")
x1.grid(column =2,row =2)


def redirector(inputStr):
txt.insert(INSERT, inputStr)

sys.stdout.write = redirector     

def ok():
redirector("Thanks for using the app")
master.quit() 


label1 = Label(text="  Welcome to the app",bg="#C2DFFF",font=("Times New Roman",18))
label1.grid(column=0,row=0)
label2 = Label(text="Ma: ",bg="#C2DFFF")
label2.grid(column=0,row=2)

txt = ScrolledText(master, bg="#C2DFFF", width = 97, height= 25, font = "Arial 11")
txt.grid(column = 0, row = 14, columnspan=3)

button = Button(master, text="OK", default ='active',command=ok).grid(column=2,row=11)
button = Button(master, text="Reset", default ='active',command=reset).grid(column=2,row=12)
button = Button(master, text ="Cancel",command = cancel).grid(column=0,row=11)

C1 = Checkbutton(master, state = ACTIVE, variable = mvar)
C1.grid(column = 1, row=2)
C2 = Checkbutton(master, state = ACTIVE, variable = mvar1)
C2.grid(column = 1, row=3)


master.mainloop()
```

[This is how the GUI looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzPM9.png)

Comment: Have you verified command line is using the same version of Python?

Comment: @RJ7 I run it with `python3 app.py`. In the process I've also installed Anaconda, so I guess it's not running the same version. How would I be able to run it from the same basic 3.6.4 version in terminal?

Comment: In terminal type python3 and see if the version you are using in IDLE matches the output in first line.

Comment: No, it definitely doesn't, that's the problem. The layout of the GUI is different, but most importantly it just closes after I provide input and click the 'ok' button (no error message, but no output either). Underneath the post there is a link to how to GUI looks like if it helps. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generally reassign `sys.stdout.write` - it is normally a read-only attribute of a built-in file object.  The proper way to do output redirection is to assign a new object to `sys.stdout`, that has a `write()` method.

Your code works in IDLE only because IDLE has already replaced the built-in `sys.stdout` with its own redirection object, which is fully modifiable.

Comment: I thought already it had to do with that line. I'm very new to all of this, so I don't know in practice how to code your suggestion. Would you please be so kind to give me a more detailed example?